# How to build mingw32-make

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

I've just build a gcc 5.2.0 on windows according to this material:
http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/
Everything went well. But then I've tried to build Qt with this newly built gcc and I'm getting an error that there is no mingw32-make. Checked directory and no, there isn't one.
But then I checked previously installed gcc, which was work of TDM, downloaded from:
http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/
and yes, in his build there is mingw32-make.
So, the question is, how is it that he has that tool, and many other which are absent in my build are present in his?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create from the gcc5.2.0 source, a build then you've just created the gcc compiler with all its necessary files. e.g. `gcc-5.2.0.exe, gcc.exe, g++.exe, etc.`

**NOT** the MinGW runtime environment for gcc, which contains the `mingw32-make.exe` !

if you follow your link from your question [here](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/) you build it with the cygwin `make.exe`.

It's better to download the `mingw 32` binary [runtime environment for gcc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)
or

MinGW64 [runtime environment for gcc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)

Then you have all the files needed to work with QT.

**if you want to create a mingw build from source, you need first a `MinGW runtime environment` then you can use that to build your own mingw32-make.exe.**